# Symfony2 Bundles resource file missing

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, tinymce

I install many bundle in my Symfony2 project (I use Symfony 2.8). I follow doc to install these bundles with composer. But when I try to access page many ressource file are missing (error 404).

For example, with the Bundle TinymceBundle.

> web/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js

Is missing.

The bundle actually work but this file is missing.

This is my composer.json :

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "codeplex/phpexcel": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.1.1",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.1.1",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "@stable",
        "gregwar/captcha-bundle": "1.0.12",
        "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle": "dev-master",
        "egulias/email-validator": "~1.2",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^1.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.2",
        "stfalcon/tinymce-bundle": "1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin",
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.6-dev"
        }
    } 
}
```

I don't understand why the files isn't in the web/js, can you help me ?

**Edit :**

There is my **stylesheet block** :

```
{% block stylesheet %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/DT_bootstrap.css') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/datatables.responsive.css') }}" />
    {{ tinymce_init({
        theme: {'simple':{'language': app.request.locale, 'height': 200 }},
        toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
        autosave_ask_before_unload: false })
    }}

{% endblock %}
```

And my **linkscript block** :

```
{% block linkscript %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/dataTable/datatables.responsive.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks !

Comment: I assume you did a "composer update" ?

Comment: Yes I did a composer update

Comment: Try `php app/console assets:install web/`

Comment: I dit it too, I followed the doc :x

Answer (score 1):

If bundle assets are missing (they are not created in assets folder) you maybe don't add this part of code to AppKernel:

```
<?php
// ...
public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new Stfalcon\Bundle\TinymceBundle\StfalconTinymceBundle(),
    );
}
```

Actually I have downloaded Symfony 2.8 and stfalcon/tinymce-bundle - you only need to add code to AppKernel, then run

```
php app/console assets:install web/
```

And then add to twig template this part:

```
{{ tinymce_init() }}
```

After that all files should be injected. This function will use this path to include tinemce:

```
web/bundles/stfalcontinymce/vendor/tinymce/tinymce.min.js
```

To sum up. If assets file not appeared after running console command, probably you didn't add bundle to AppKernel or maybe you are looking for this files in wrong place. In default, assets will be placed in

```
/web/bundles/*
```

Comment: I added bundle to appKernel. And the ressource file are in web/bundle, but the browser search in web/js :x

Comment: Ok, so this is connected with another issue - actually not the browser is searching in wrong path rather code is giving wrong paths :P Please show how you add resource files like css and js in you template. Which files can't load?

Comment: I cant now but tomorrow. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ok, please add this to ur question, I will look at that tomorrow.

Comment: @Eraseth, were does the code [from your proposed edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12128494) come from?

Comment: @Eraseth, Why did you add `js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js` manually? Do you want to have newer version of tinymce rather than is in bundle? When you run command `php app/console assets:install web/`, the path to tinymce will be `web/bundles/stfalcontinymce/vendor/tinymce/tinymce.min.js`. Also you don't have to add this resource manually. It's added automatically when you run `{{ tinymce_init() }}`. Please check the page source, tinymce.min.js will be added. Right now I'm not sure where is the problem with that.